# Proof of Lagrange's Identity in vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to prove Lagrange's identity $(\textbf{A}\times\textbf{B})\cdot(\textbf{C}\times\textbf{D}) = (\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{C})(\textbf{B}\cdot\textbf{D}) - (\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{D})(\textbf{B}\cdot\textbf{C})$.

I am unsure how to do this. Would it be enough to merely write the right-hand side in terms of components and show that it equals the left-hand side solved in terms of components, or is there another proof? Thanks.

Comment: "Would it be enough..., or is there another proof?"  Those are entirely different questions.  Yes it is enough, but sure there are other proofs, too.  Have you tried the method you suggested?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I've tried it, but I am looking for something more elegant if there is such a way.

Comment: And did it work?

Answer (score 3):

The functions $f,g:(\mathbb R^3)^4\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(A,B,C,D)=(A\times B)\cdot(C\times D)$ and $g(A,B,C,D)=(A\cdot C)(B\cdot D) -(A\cdot D)(B\cdot C)$ are [multilinear maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map), and therefore they are determined by their values when $A,B,C,$ and $D$ are chosen from the standard basis vectors $\hat i,\hat j,\hat k$ for $\mathbb R^3$.  At first glance that leaves $3^4=81$ things to check, but both $f$ and $g$ have the properties that switching $A$ and $B$, or $C$ and $D$, merely changes the sign, and thus $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ can be chosen from $\{(\hat i,\hat j),(\hat i,\hat k),(\hat j,\hat k)\}$, leaving only $3^2=9$ things to check.